# How to replace detail pane with specific pages in MasterDetailsView on master item click

Tags: c#, xaml, uwp, windows-10, uwp-xaml

Whenever the user clicks an item in the Master pane, how can I show a specific page in the details pane? I created a Frame in the Details pane for easier & efficient page loading, but I don't know if it is more efficient to do this from a click event or specify the page names in the item class and read the value from there.

Destination pages: Page A, Page B, Page C, Page D

**MainPage.xaml**

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="MyConveter" />
</Page.Resources>
<Grid x:Name="RootGrid">
    <controls:MasterDetailsView
        x:Name="MyMasterDetailsView"
        BackButtonBehavior="Automatic"
        CompactModeThresholdWidth="720"
        ItemsSource="{x:Bind Emails}"
        NoSelectionContent="Select an item to view"
        >
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Grid>
                    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                    <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Margin="0,8">
                        <TextBlock 
                            Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}" 
                            Text="{Binding From}" />
                        <TextBlock
                            Opacity=".6"
                            Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                            Text="{Binding Body}"
                            />
                    </StackPanel>

                    <Button
                        x:Name="MoreBtn"
                        Grid.Column="1"
                        Margin="10"
                        Padding="10"
                        HorizontalAlignment="Right"
                        VerticalAlignment="Top"
                        Background="Transparent"
                        Click="MoreBtn_Click"
                        Command="{Binding ElementName=RootGrid, Path=DataContext.OpenDialog}"
                        CommandParameter="{Binding}"
                        Content="&#xE712;"
                        FontFamily="Segoe MDL2 Assets"
                        Visibility="{Binding ShowButton, Converter={StaticResource MyConveter}}"
                        />
                </Grid>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.ItemTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Frame x:Name="DetailFrame"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <StackPanel HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center">
                    <SymbolIcon RenderTransformOrigin=".5,.5" Symbol="Mail">
                        <SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                            <CompositeTransform ScaleX="2" ScaleY="2" />
                        </SymbolIcon.RenderTransform>
                    </SymbolIcon>
                    <TextBlock
                        Margin="0,12"
                        FontSize="24"
                        Text="{Binding}"
                        />
                </StackPanel>
            </DataTemplate>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.NoSelectionContentTemplate>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
            <CommandBar>
                <AppBarButton Icon="Back" Label="Back" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="Forward" Label="Forward" />

                <CommandBar.Content>
                    <TextBlock Margin="12,14">
                        <Run Text="{Binding Emails.Count}" />
                        <Run Text="Items" />
                    </TextBlock>
                </CommandBar.Content>
            </CommandBar>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.MasterCommandBar>
        <controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
            <CommandBar>
                <AppBarButton Icon="MailReply" Label="Reply" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="MailReplyAll" Label="Reply All" />
                <AppBarButton Icon="MailForward" Label="Forward" />
            </CommandBar>
        </controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsCommandBar>
    </controls:MasterDetailsView>
</Grid>
```

**MainPage.xaml.cs**

```
 public sealed partial class MainPage : Page
    {
        public List<Email> Emails { get; set; }
        public MainPage()
        {
            this.InitializeComponent();
            this.DataContext = this;
            Emails = MyEmailManager.GetEmails();
        }
        public ICommand OpenDialog
        {
            get
            {
                return new CommadEventHandler<Email>((s) => OpenDialogCommandFun(s));
            }
        }
        private async void OpenDialogCommandFun(Email s)
        {
            ContentDialog dialogServiceUpdates = new ContentDialog
            {
                Title = s.From,
                Content = s.Body,
                CloseButtonText = "OK"
            };

            ContentDialogResult result = await dialogServiceUpdates.ShowAsync();
        }
        private void MoreBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {

        }
    }

    public class Email
    {
        public string From { get; set; }
        public string Body { get; set; }
        public bool ShowButton { get; set; }
    }

    public class MyEmailManager
    {
        public static List<Email> GetEmails()
        {
            var MyEmails = new List<Email>
        {
            new Email
            {
                From = "Steve Johnson",
                Body = "Are you available for lunch tomorrow? A client would like to discuss a project with you.",
                ShowButton = true
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "Pete Davidson",
                Body = "Don't forget the kids have their soccer game this Friday. We have to supply end of game snacks.",
                ShowButton = false
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "OneDrive",
                Body = "Your new album.\r\nYou uploaded some photos to your OneDrive and automatically created an album for you.",
                ShowButton = false
            },
            new Email
            {
                From = "Twitter",
                Body = "Here are some people we think you might like to follow:\r\n.@randomPerson\r\nAPersonYouMightKnow",
                ShowButton = true
            }
        };

            return MyEmails;
        }
    }

    public class CommadEventHandler<T> : ICommand
    {
        public event EventHandler CanExecuteChanged;

        public Action<T> action;
        public bool CanExecute(object parameter)
        {
            return true;
        }

        public void Execute(object parameter)
        {
            this.action((T)parameter);
        }
        public CommadEventHandler(Action<T> action)
        {
            this.action = action;

        }
    }
```

**Expected result**

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/ffb346f8-40fe-40a5-b194-2fc63d292047/wpf-frame-contents-binding-not-updating?forum=wpf

Comment: @LDS It's a shame there is no helpful C# tutorial available for this. The code on that page is all in VB and (even still) looks outdated.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3529765/wpf-page-to-page-navigation-from-listbox-menu-employing-frame-technique

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest your refer  my previous [reply](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49531625/7254781). [`Frame`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame?view=winrt-19041) has [`SourcePageType`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.frame.sourcepagetype?view=winrt-19041) property that use to bind the specific page type in  mvvm model. So you could insert `Frame` into `DetailsTemplate`. And binding with model `From` property then use converter to return the matched page type.

Example Code.

```
<Page.Resources>
    <converters:BoolToVisibilityConverter x:Key="MyConveter" />
    <local:PageConverter x:Name="PageConverter" />
</Page.Resources>

......

<controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
    <DataTemplate>
        <RelativePanel Margin="24">
            <TextBlock
                Margin="12,-6,0,0"
                Style="{ThemeResource SubtitleTextBlockStyle}"
                Text="{Binding From}"
                />
            <TextBlock
                x:Name="Body"
                Margin="0,12,0,0"
                Style="{ThemeResource BodyTextBlockStyle}"
                Text="{Binding Body}"
                TextWrapping="Wrap"
                />
            <Frame
                Margin="0,100,0,0"
                RelativePanel.AlignBottomWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignHorizontalCenterWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignLeftWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignRightWithPanel="True"
                RelativePanel.AlignTopWithPanel="True"
                SourcePageType="{Binding From, Converter={StaticResource PageConverter}, Mode=TwoWay}"
                />
        </RelativePanel>
    </DataTemplate>
</controls:MasterDetailsView.DetailsTemplate>
```

**Converter**

```
public class PageConverter : IValueConverter
{
    public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        Type page = null;
        switch (value as string)
        {
            case "Steve Johnson":
                page = typeof(FistPage);
                break;
            case "Pete Davidson":
                page = typeof(SecondPage);
                break;
            case "OneDrive":
                page = typeof(FistPage);
                break;
            case "Twitter":
                page = typeof(SecondPage);
                break;
            default:
                break;
        }

        return page;
    }

    public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, string language)
    {
        throw new NotImplementedException();
    }
}
```

And here is code [sample](https://github.com/ZhuMingHao/MasterDetailViewTest).

Comment: What about the click event for the `GridView`? The following code does not work for me as I was using a separate class before.

`private async void GridView_ItemClick(object sender, ItemClickEventArgs e)
{ var item = MyGridView.ContainerFromItem(e.ClickedItem) as GridViewItem;
    
    
             if (item.Title == "System")
             {
             }
             }`

Comment: I have replied your same thread in QA please check.

Comment: How can I use a string resource? Instead of `case "Steve Johnson"` I want to use `case resourceLoader.GetString("SteveJohnson/Text")`

Comment: hi @MacaronLover, please avoid post the new question in the comments, pleas make new thread and share the link.